# css media query with class name

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

The following html has an image which sizes differently based on my @media query.
It works fine without any class names, but once I add class names (using `Angular ngClass directive`) the media rule doesn't fire any longer.

1. Working fine - media rule is applied, and image is 105x105 where height >= 999px.

```css
div {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    align-self: center;
    
    @media screen and (min-height: 999px) {
      width: 105px;
      height: 105px;
    }
}
```

```html
     <div>
      <img
        *ngIf="svgImageData"
        src="{{ svgImageData }}"
        width="{{ width }}"
        height="{{ height }}"
      />
    </div>
```

And I can see when I inspect the element, `min-height: 999px` is applied:

[image: media query]

With the class names, the media rule does **not** fire - i.e. I commented the 105px height and width, and moved it INTO the class rules below media query:

```css
div {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    align-self: center;
    
    @media screen and (min-height: 999px) {
      //width: 105px;
      //height: 105px;
      .gcl-no-scrollbar {
        width: 105px !important;
        height: 105px !important;
      }      
      .gcl-scrollbar{
        width: 95px;
        height: 95px;
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div [ngClass]="gclScrollbarIsVisible ? 'gcl-scrollbar' : 'gcl-no-scrollbar'" >
      <img
        *ngIf="svgImageData"
        src="{{ svgImageData }}"
        width="{{ width }}"
        height="{{ height }}"
      />
    </div>
```

Here I see that the `gcl-no-scrollbar` is applied to the html element, but NOT the media query rule `.gcl-scrollbar { ... }`

[image: media qry not applied]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a cascading issue. The issue was simply that I forgot to add `&.`:

```
div {
width: 85px; 
height: 85px;
&.gcl-scrollbar{
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
}
align-self: center;
```

}